# How to share files from any path using a FileProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

My app allows the user to download some content and store it in the folder of his choice. 
I want to create a ContentProvider to share those files, but I don't know how to do that when the downloaded files are stored outside of the app default path.

I tried to decalre to following filePath:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="." path="/" />
</paths>
```

but it just try to match shared file path with the root of the app default folder.
Is there a way share files from the SD card for example ?
If so how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way share files from the SD card for example ?

Use `<external-path>` instead of `<files-path>`. The documentation for `FileProvider` [has a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61170); `<external-path>` maps to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this was an example. I only know the path at runtime because the user can change it at any time. Is there a way to set the path at the root level, so I can share any file ?

Comment: @user1026605: "Is there a way to set the path at the root level, so I can share any file ?" -- no. "I only know the path at runtime because the user can change it at any time" -- however, if your app is doing the file I/O, the path has to be some place that you can read and write. The three options on `FileProvider` cover the primary places that you can read and write that is supported by the Android SDK. Hence, if you create three elements in the `FileProvider` metadata, you cover all three of your possible roots.

Comment: @user1026605: If you are putting files someplace that `FileProvider` does not support (e.g., removable media via `getExternalFilesDirs()`), you will need to create your own clone of `FileProvider`, as I did with [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider).

Comment: I just found out about <root-path> which seems be be the perfect match for what I'm trying to do. I will do more tests

Comment: @user1026605: That's not documented, so I would be hesitant about relying upon it.

Comment: I just find out in the FileProvider code, and it's public. I will see if I use this or not, but for now it seems to work fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent several hours trying to figure out what happened with external-path