# Does Android's FileProvider actually support external-files-path?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, android-fileprovider, android-7.0-nougat

I've run into the FileUriExposedException stuff where you try to send a file:/// Uri to another app (in this case the camera), and I should be using a FileProvider instead (causes a crash on api 24 Nougat).

In our app, we generate a File using Context's `getExternalFilesDir(String)` method:

```
context.getExternalFilesDir("attachments");
```

The [FileProvider documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles) leads me to believe I should be using `external-files-path` in my `paths.xml` if I want the functionality to be the same as is now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="attachments"
        path="attachments/" />
</paths>
```

But after googling some more, I found a few things that make me think there's issues with FileProvider, or at least FileProvider's documentation...

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61170
- @commonsWare
  answer and comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276915/921988
- The README of this active library that says it adds support for `external-files-dir` https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#metadata-elements
- Also, I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains ...` right now, but that might be caused by something else.

So

1. Am I right in thinking I should use `external-files-path` if I want to match how my app currently works?
2. Is the documentation/FileProvider really broken/incorrect and I should use something like [cwac-provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) instead?

**UPDATE**

For completeness, as @CommonsWare recommended below, using the 24.2.0 version of `support-v4` is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking I should use external-files-path if I want to match how my app currently works?

Yes. Though do note that [`getExternalFilesDir()` does not officially support `"attachments"` as a parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), so do not be surprised if your app breaks someday.

> Is the documentation/FileProvider really broken/incorrect

Well, I see the code for `external-files-path` support in the sources JAR for 24.2.0 of the new `support-core-utils` artifact. `support-v4`, as of 24.2.0, has been subdivided into a series of separate artifacts, and `FileProvider` lives in `support-core-utils`.

So, try using 24.2.0 of `support-v4` (or `support-core-utils` if you do not need all of `support-v4`).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the very speedy and very helpful response! I will try 24.2 support-v4. On the other note -- you mean it doesn't support "attachments" in that the `String type` argument I provide should ideally be one of the ones mentioned in the documentation (beginning with `DIRECTORY_...`)?

Comment: @Josh: Yes, ideally it is `null` or one of the stated supported values. *Probably* they will continue to support arbitrary strings, since they have never implemented checking here, but we cannot rule out the possibility that they will start enforcing the rules.

Comment: ah ok i understand. thanks for pointing that out! it's something we will look at. very helpful stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar scenario of sharing a private file to the camera to upload full quality image without putting a permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

I was able to make it work by using the  as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.santhoshn.appprivateimageupload/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Here is the working sample app https://github.com/santbob/AppPrivateImageUpload

Comment: While the link may answer the question it is always best to include the key parts of the information in your answer. This enables users to find the information even if the link is broken. Also, this lets users find the information more easily than having to look through an external link.

Comment: thanks for the input, will update my original response